# Python Regex: multiple regrex causing problem

Tags: python, regex

A basic version of this problem is using an regex to translate something like `abc like '%FFddsdE%'` into `LOWER(abc) like '%ffddsde%'`
and the following code works well

```
import re
text = "abc like '%FFddsdE%'"
print("before: " + text)
text = re.sub('([^ ^\n]+?) ?like ?\'([^ ]+)\'', 
             lambda s: f'LOWER({s.group(1)}) like \'{s.group(2).lower()}\'', 
             text, flags=re.I)
print("after: " + text)


#the output is
#before: abc like '%FFddsdE%'
#after: LOWER(abc) like '%ffddsde%'
```

However, everything crash down if we want to expand this problem a little bit, to both `like` and `not like`

```
import re

text = "abc not like '%FFddsdE%' and bcd like '%XyZ%'"
print("before: " + text)
text = re.sub('([^ ^\n]+?) ?not like ?\'([^ ]+)\'', 
             lambda s: f'LOWER({s.group(1)}) not like \'{s.group(2).lower()}\'', 
             text, flags=re.I)
text = re.sub('([^ ^\n]+?) ?like ?\'([^ ]+)\'', 
             lambda s: f'LOWER({s.group(1)}) like \'{s.group(2).lower()}\'', 
             text, flags=re.I)
print("after: " + text)

#the output is
#before: abc not like '%FFddsdE%' and bcd like '%XyZ%'
#after: LOWER(abc) LOWER(not) like '%ffddsde%' and LOWER(bcd) like '%xyz%'
```

It gives `LOWER(not)` in the output.

I am using python 3 btw. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use another group to match `like` and `not like` at the same time.

```py
import re
text = "abc not like '%FFddsdE%' and bcd like '%XyZ%'"
print("before: " + text)
text = re.sub('([^ ^\n]+?) ?(like|not like) ?\'([^ ]+)\'',
             lambda s: f'LOWER({s.group(1)}) {s.group(2)} \'{s.group(3).lower()}\'',
             text, flags=re.I)
print("after: " + text)

# before: abc not like '%FFddsdE%' and bcd like '%XyZ%'
# after: LOWER(abc) not like '%ffddsde%' and LOWER(bcd) like '%xyz%'
```